# Trying forever. Can't change CSS font color

Tags: css, fonts, colors

I seriously have worked on this FOR-EVER!!!

Why the heck isn't my menu color change via the CSS?

I don't know if it's the Wordpress theme interfering or what, but I need a fresh pair of eyes on this website: http://rivercityhopestreet.org/

Help!!!

## GoingBananas

Comment: Please post your code and explain us exactly what you want to change..

Comment: Did you try inspecting your element? You can see which CSS rules apply and which have been overridden for your element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should learn how to use **web debugging tool**s. For chrome it's **right click -> inspect element**. Then you can find Your menu element and see what's setting the styles. 
In added image You can see that Your style is accepted, but overridden by style in `index` file. Either it's style in php file itself or some Javascript.  
You can either change the setting in the index file or (not the best way) set it to background: #40c2a6; !important` in your style.min.css
[image]

Also if You cannot figure something out, in Developer Tools click on the Html element, then click on "Computed" on the right side  and then click on the specific style - it will show you where that real value is set at.  
 
[image]

Hope this helps You in the future!

Answer (score -1):

```
#menu-primary-items>li a {
    color: #888;
}
```

search this and change the color..

[image: It changes..]

Answer (score -1):

Edit this in custom css.

```
#menu-primary-items>li a{
color : #000;
}
```

if it not works then put `!important` in color attribute.